# MetaMask Registering Contract Methods - Not Working

Tags: web3js, ether, metamask, etherscan, fantom

I was following these docs:

https://docs.metamask.io/guide/registering-function-names.html#verify

After verifying my contract and using the write section, my methods still aren't verified by MetaMask, this is causing the ERC20 Token amount I'm trying to send not appear in my transaction on MetaMask.

Please note: I'm using the Fantom test net, maybe MetaMask isn't looking at method signatures on the FTM test net? (chain id: 4002)

Any ideas?

Cheers